# How to add two rows straight between two Bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want two rows I added straight in a line.

Like this image.

[image]

After, I divide bootstrap to two `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`.

In `col-md-8` I continues divide to `col-md-3` contain `<hr>` tag and `col-md-9` contain `<h4>` text and all content.

In `col-md-4` > it will create to `col-md-12`. In this columns, I don't need divide `<hr>` in any columns.

Next, I add text with `<hr>` tag. So, in two columns it not straight.

My code like this:

```css
div.hr_tinkhuyenmai{
    height: 1px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #ffa800;
}
div.title_tinkhuyenmai{
    font-family: tahoma;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
}

div.group_title_hr{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: roboto_regular;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right
    margin-top: 20px;
}

div.title_child_breakingnews{
    width: 10%;
    float: right
}
div.hr_child_breakingnews{
    width: 30%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ffa800;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid remove_padding" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="title_tinkhuyenmai">
          <div class="col-md-3 hr_tinkhuyenmai"></div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <h4>TIN KHUYẾN MÃI</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="group_title_hr col-md-12">
          <div class="title_child_breakingnews text-right">TIN NỔI BẬT</div>
          <div class="hr_child_breakingnews text-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to design like the image, you have to follow this instruction:

```
------------:------------------- ----------------- -------------------------------
|    <hr>   |       TEXT       | |  Middle Div   | | Text |         <hr>         |
-------------------------------- ----------------- -------------------------------
            |                  |                        |   C1   |
            |      Image       |                        |   C2   |
            --------------------                        |   C3   |
```

Code pattern: (For header part)

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="col-md-3">

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-9">

           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="col-md-x">

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-x">

           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

As your code:

```
<div class="container-fluid remove_padding" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;margin-top: 20px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="title_tinkhuyenmai">
                            <div class="col-md-3 hr_tinkhuyenmai"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <h4>TIN KHUYẾN MÃI</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="col-md-4 group_title_hr">
                                <div>TIN NỔI BẬT</div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-7" style="margin-top: 17px; ">
                                <div class="hr_child_breakingnews text-right"></div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

** Lets finish your task. :P